# How do show a result table from two 'select'? SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have 2 queries:
**First query:**

```
select TableB.name, count(TableB.name) from TableB group by TableB.name
```

**result:**

```
 name | count
 Jack | 2
 Marry| 1
```

and
**Second query:**

```
select DISTINCT TableA.kName, TableA.Value from TableA inner join TableB 
ON
TableA.kName=TableB.name
```

**result:**

```
kName | Value
Jack  | 1
Marry | 3
```

But I need result table:

```
kName | Value | newColumn
Jack  |  1    | 2
Marry |  3    | 1
```

where the newColumn is result of first query, How can to do it? help, please.

**maybe:**

```
select DISTINCT TableA.kName, TableA.value, 
(select TableB.name, count(TableB.name) from TableB group by TableB.name) 
AS 
newColumn from TableA inner join TableB ON TableA.kName=TableB.name
```

but this is not work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT tableB.name, tableA.value, count(tableB.name) as newColum FROM tableB
JOIN tableA ON tableB.name = tableA.kname
GROUP BY tableB.name,tableA.value
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select kname, value, "newColumn"
from
    (
        select name, count(name) as "newColumn"
        from tb
        group by name
    ) tb
    inner join
    (
        select distinct kname, value
        from ta
    ) ta ta.kname = tb.name
```